# Flutter, accessing list of items in a map

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary

I have map with items in it, I wanna get all the words from it into a new list, how can I do that?

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> englishFrequencyWordList = [
  {'word': 'test5', 'frequency': '1'},
  {'word': 'test3', 'frequency': '3'},
  {'word': 'test2', 'frequency': '4'},
  {'word': 'test4', 'frequency': '2'},
  {'word': 'test1', 'frequency': '5'}
];
```

Like this isn't working?
List newWordList = englishFrequencyWordList.word; ???

I need result to be: `['test5', 'test3', 'test2', 'test4', 'test1']`

Thank you

Comment: `print(englishFrequencyWordList.map((f) => f['word']).toList());` - for more info refer to [Iterable collections](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just map the list to a new one.

```dart
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> englishFrequencyWordList = [
    {'word': 'test5', 'frequency': '1'},
    {'word': 'test3', 'frequency': '3'},
    {'word': 'test2', 'frequency': '4'},
    {'word': 'test4', 'frequency': '2'},
    {'word': 'test1', 'frequency': '5'}
  ];

  final wordList =
      englishFrequencyWordList.map((item) => item['word']!).toList();

  print(wordList);
```